# Dynamically created array with given number of elements

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

I am not 100% sure whether I correctly allocated an array with 10 elements

```
char *str;


str = (int*)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
```

The task was to allocate memory of string with 10 elements.

Have I done it correctly or do I have to add "+ 1" because of the '\0' at the end.

Thanks!

Comment: `char *str`, why what where?!

Comment: Note that in c, you [don't cast pointers returned by malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: you are allocating too much memory, str is a char pointer not an int pointer.  so you only have to allocate 11 bytes. which can be done like this `str = malloc(11);`

Comment: What is your "element"? Character or int? Make up your mind.

Comment: `\0` terminator only applies to strings. If you need a string of 10 characters, then you need 11 bytes. Nowhere in your question did you mention a "string" or "character string", so it's unclear what you want.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for explanation between those two

Answer (score 6):

You have allocated many times more than you need. (`sizeof(int)` times to be precise). The correct would be

```
#define MAXLEN 10
...
str = malloc(sizeof *str*(MAXLEN+1));
```

Note that this will be `sizeof(char)` which is `1`. So you can do this also

```
str = malloc(MAXLEN+1);
```

Check the return value of `malloc` as shown below: (`malloc` might not be able to service the request, it might return a null pointer. It is important to
check for this to prevent later attempts to dereference the null pointer).

```
str = malloc(MAXLEN+1);
if(!str){
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Also `void*` to `char*` conversion is implicit - you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc`.

`sizeof(*str)` is a cleaner way to get the size of the type of the element for which we are allocating memory in `str`. The benefit is when you are later changing the code and making `str` point to an allocated memory which will contain `int`-s you don't need to look for `sizeof(char)` and then replace it with `sizeof(int)` it is done here by using `sizeof(*str)` automatically.

Comment: But why do you do sizeof(*str) instead of sizeof(char) for example?

Comment: @Desibre93.: Read the last part of the answer.

Comment: Thanks alot, but can I also write it simply like this str = malloc(11) ?

Comment: @Desibre93.: Yes I have mentioned it.You can do that also..Instead of using 11..I used macro to hold that magic number

Comment: never write  `malloc(11)`. When you read the code later - whats 11? (why not 12 or 42?)

Comment: @Desibre93 basic programming technique: use constant defines for things like buffer sizes, string lengths, etc. Do not hard-code them in the code. For example, if you just used 11, then when you write a loop, say, to go through your buffer, you'd need a 10 or 11 there as well. Then later when you need to change the code to handle a different number, you have to find all the places that have that number. So use `#define MAXLEN 10` for the number of characters, and `MAXLEN+1` for the size of the needed buffer. Then if it has to change, you only have to change the value in `#define MAXLEN 10`.

Comment: @coderredoc if I write it like this char *string = (char\*)malloc((MAXLEN+1)*sizeof(char)));
Is this correct as well? Will it work?